# How to modify the text area in more than one element using Javascript؟

Tags: javascript, html

When designing a task, I write the name of the task, and then press the Add button, the item appears, and next to it, the Finish button. When I press Finish, the item appears in the Tasks section that has been executed, and next to the item, a Notes button. When I press the Notes button, the text area appears and disappears, and in the text area there is an edit button. When I click on it, I can write a comment inside the text area, and by pressing the Save button, the modification is locked to the problematic text area? When I add more than one element, the entire text area takes the same first comment, and I want each element to be stable in writing the text area so that I can modify the comment in any element without affecting the rest of the elements

[https://codepen.io/amr77/pen/QWBqLVJ?fbclid=IwAR2JmTaZUliSixWR3vei3-zQdJOcIOuxm-eLs5KRgtkqxO8I3QRfwGFJ6Yw](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.